# What is pattern python

Tags: python

I've been programming in Java for the past year and this weekend I decided to throw myself in the deep-end and build a text-classifier in **Python3**. While naturally there's syntax distinction, there's a lot of conceptual similarities that I'm familiar with. However, I've come across `pattern`, something I've yet to encounter in Java.

I've done some research and understand it relates to design-patterns, the 23 GoF, patterns allow for reusability of code and improves interactions with objects etc. **But I don't understand how `pattern`is used in this following block of code.** For context, the text-classifier is looping through each sentence in the training data, manipulating the pre-instantiated lists, `words`, `classes` and `documents`. Here's the link to what I'm following - https://machinelearnings.co/text-classification-using-neural-networks-f5cd7b8765c6

```
for pattern in training_data(pattern['sentence'])
    words.extend(w)
    documents.append((w, pattern['class']))
    if pattern['class'] not in classes:
        classes.append(pattern['classes'])
```

Cheers for your help!

Comment: Where is this code from? No one can really say what's going on without seeing the code in context.

Comment: It's just a variable named `pattern`.

Comment: I don't see your code in the page you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with *design patterns*. In this case, *pattern* is machine learning-related, not programming-related. A *pattern* is just an input vector. A dataset consists of a set of patterns. In supervised learning, each pattern has a corresponding class/output.

The aim of pattern recognition/classification is: given the pattern (input vector) predict the value of its class.